# Objective-C start loop from the beginning

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a question related with loops and iterations

I have a situation:

```
for (Item *item in items)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        iterateAgain;
    }
}
```

Objective-C provided `continue` operator would just start with a new iteration. Operator `break` would break out of whole loop.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Why do you keeping editing the question, thus making the solution different?

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. No more editing!

Comment: Well my solution assumes `items` is an `NSSet`, which was the 1st edit.  The principle should be clear though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't using *fast enumeration*, which is what you appear to be using; use index-based looping instead:

```
NSSet *items = [Model items];
NSArray *itemsArray = [items allObjects];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [itemsArray count]; index++) {
    Item *item = itemsArray[index];
    // ...
    if (condition) {
        index = 0;
        // Possibly use 'continue' here, depending what else is in the loop
    }
}
```